# Setting Syntax Highlight for Specific Folder (not Extension)

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I know that in Sublime Text 3 I can use the bottom right drop-up menu to temporarily change a file's syntax highlighting; and I know that I can, from this same menu, change the syntax highlighting for all files with the same extension.

However, I want to do this for just a specific folder. Is there any way to do that?

The case is that I am working on a Ruby on Rails project. Most files with extension `.rb` I want to open as Ruby, fine. But files under `features/step_definitions`, which have the `.rb` extension, I want to open using the Cucumber Steps syntax highlight (so just that one folder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [ApplySyntax](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ApplySyntax) package.
See the "RSpec/RSpec" example in settings.
You can also add a comment on the first line to specify the Cucumber Steps syntax, see "XML/XML" example in settings for "first_line" option usage.

Comment: That worked perfect out of the box for exactly what I wanted, but it's great that it can be customized to whatever needs. Thanks!